# python os.system() not running with my permissions?

Tags: python, security, permissions, grep, os.system

I am trying to grep through a file using `os.system("grep 'regex' /path/to/file.log")`. I know the regex is correct, and the command works when run from the shell, but once I try running the script I get the following error:

```
sh: /path/to/file.log: Permission denied
```

Is the os module not running with my permissions? Also, is there a better way to do this? I need to find specific lines in a 40,000+ line file.

THANKS!

Comment: you could try `os.system("id -a")` to see what it's running as, but note that you generally shouldn't use `os.system` unless you're *very* sure about the escaping rules for whatever shell it happens to run as — `subprocess.check_call` is much better.

Comment: Note that the error message starts `sh:`, not `grep:`.  If I try to grep through a file I don't have permission to read, I get `grep: path.to.log: Permission denied`.  Feels to me like your regex (and maybe path, although that's less likely) is improperly escaped and so `/path/to/file.log` is trying to be executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably easier to do this using Python's built in regex module, `re`, rather than shelling out to `grep`.

```
import re

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(regex, line):
            print line,
```

I know this doesn't answer the question directly but it's probably the right solution to the underlying problem. I think this falls into the "is there a better way to do this?" part of your question.